# Clarification on How to access the Java+ Xml application in PHP based web portal

Tags: java, php, html, xml

I Require a clarification on one Technical Implementation to check its feasible or not.

I have one VPS server which has a Java Environment and I have one more dedicated server which doesnot have a Java Environment where i have built my PHP based web application,

In the VPS environment I am planning to implement the XML based application using the Observer pattern with java and DOM Parsers and make that application available at say for example
123.124.125.65/XML_Works/Sample,xml file

Now My doubt is that:  1)is it possbile to access this application in dedicated Server where the java environment is not there. 
2)if yes, then is it possible to access that java + XML application in IFrame in PHP based web portal.

Comment: If your VPS server has web server running, you can integrate that with php server easily. And other secured option could be think about implement webservice.

Answer (score 2):

1) No JVM = no java running on that machine
2) The most common solution I saw (and am using) is to externalize the java functionality you want as a web service or servlet and package it as a *.war*
Then use some web container such as tomcat to load that war and use a connector to connect calls to tomcat to your PHP server.

So the configuration I use is, Java as war, [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) as web container, [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) as PHP server and [mod_jk connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi) for communication between servers.

Note that the mod_jk connector also supports other web servers.

Comment: JVM will be there in the VPS machine where the actual application will be build and deployed, I am trying that application in the dedicated machine and display in the html or php pages in the Iframes,

Comment: In that case I would just suggest a web service that return the XML or html you want with some minor processing in the php, use Tomcat or Jetty for running the webservice or you can even use [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) for a declarative way to automatically generate such a webservice.